# Check for an internet connection in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to poll google every 10 seconds to make sure that there is an active and working internet connection.  What is the best way to achieve this in Objective C?

Using CURL would be ideal, but do not believe it has Objective C bindings.

Thanks

*Note, this is for OSX **not** for iOS.*

Comment: What platform is this for if not iPhone? OSX? Something else? Objective-C doesn't have a built in internet connectivity function. Something must be built on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Reachability APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html) work in Mac OS X, not just iOS. (And presumably the Reachability sample code will work as well, if you want a nicer Obj-C wrapper around these C APIs.)

Comment: I answered my own question. There is a notification example that will notify when the interface changes.

Comment: The problem with the Reachability API is that you are connected to a router, and the internet is not reachable from it The Reachability API will tell you that the internet is reachable, but it is a false positive.